# Is there a way to search in an __repr__ similar to a string in Python

Tags: python, string, magic-methods, repr

I'm currently working on a project, and I was hoping to use the __ repr __ method to look directly at a list and see if a value is present.

Currently, my method looks like this:

```
def __ repr__(self):
     return 'Item({!r},{!r})'.format(self._id_code, self._title)
```

Let's say I have an input of Item("Jerry","123"), then my object, rather than giving the memory address, now looks like this:

```
Item('Jerry','123')
```

However, when I try to check to see if an input matches it comes back as false. For example:

```
print('123' in Item('Jerry','123')) # This comes back as False
```

Is there a way to take an __ repr__ and make it a string that I can search over?

Thank you in advance for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

Define `__contains__` to implement value lookup.

```
class Item:
    ...

    def __contains__(self, v):
        return self._id_code == v or self._title == v


>>> assert i._id_code == 'Jerry'
>>> assert i._title = '123'
>>> '123' in i
True
>>> 'Jerry' in i
True
>>> 'Bob' in i
False
```

Comment: I told others of this issue and many of them suggested that I use the 
```__contains__```

method as it would be a better approach. Thank you for this example!